# Time compare in elixir phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to get an date input from user and compare(if it is at least 30min future) it whether it is future and save it to database.
Date from user input is like this 2018-09-26
Time from user input is like this 16:00
So I convert it to naive datetime

```
def build_naive_datetime(date, time) do
  {:ok, datetime} = NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601("#{date} #{time}:00")
  datetime
end
```

so it returns `~N[2018-09-26 16:00:00]`.

and I want to compare it.

```
def schedule_datetime_is_future?(schedule_datetime) do
    # 30 mins future from now on
    future_datetime = DateTime.to_naive(Timex.add(Timex.now, Timex.Duration.from_minutes(30)))
    case Timex.compare(schedule_datetime, future_datetime) do
      1 ->
        # schedule datetime is future
        true
      -1 ->
        # schedule datetime is not future
        false
      _ ->
        false
    end
  end
```

But Timex.now returns in my dev computer time zone time(maybe returns utc).
So compare doens't work properly.(user input datetime is local time.)
How can I do this in better way?
Do I have to change user datetime to utc time?
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not convert anything to `NaiveDateTime` in the first place since naïve date time does not have a time zone at all (hence the name.)

You probably should use [`DateTime.diff/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#diff/3):

```rb
def build_datetime(date, time) do
  with {:ok, datetime, 0} <- DateTime.from_iso8601("#{date}T#{time}:00Z"),
    do: datetime
end

def schedule_datetime_is_future?(schedule_datetime) do
  DateTime.diff(schedule_datetime, DateTime.utc_now) > 30 * 60
end
```

Comment: build_datetime(date, time) returns {:error, :missing_offset} what am I missing here?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copy-pasted the argument from your `NaiveDateTime` implementation, here it’s slightly different. Fixed.

Comment: oh Thanks!, 1 more question, If I use utc time, that means it works in any timezone? Let's say, If I run DateTime.utc_now, it returns not my local time, it returns utc time and it is different from local time, But I want my schedule job to run after 10 min from now on in my local time. how does this work?

Comment: To correctly work with timezones, one [requires **`tz_info` database**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/DateTime.html#module-where-are-my-functions). But here you do not need any TZ info because 10 minutes from now is 600 seconds of difference, no matter what TZ is used.

Comment: what if users pick a datetime from different time zone? and I need to schedule a job depend on that datetime?

Comment: What user? How come pick? The only external data given in the question is date/time, both strings without timezone.